# Display inline-block affects line height hover

Tags: html, css

I have created some "buttons" out of three divs and I have set a hover to each div so that the text drops by 5px when the user hovers over the div.

I'm using `display:inline-block` as I don't want to use `float:left`

The only problem is that when I use `display:inline-block` on the divs, it lowers the other divs instead.

Here is how it should work (using `float:left`)

[WORKING](http://jsfiddle.net/7LaT4/)

And this is what happens when I used `display:inline-block`

[NOT WORKING](http://jsfiddle.net/y47P7/)

Is there a fix for this or am I going to have to use a different solution?

Comment: set explicit `vertical-align:middle` (or top, bottom, ...) for all the inline-block elements http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/y47P7/1/

Comment: `inline-block` elements are `vertical-align:baseline;` by default.

Comment: @KingKing this solution works but when I try and add the buttons into the rest of my code it goes back to not working :/

Comment: @SaturnsEye not sure what you mean, so what's the new updated fiddle showing it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the problem!

Although KingKing's answer was correct, using `.wkd > * {vertical-align:middle;}` didn't seem to work well with the rest of my code so I had to alter it slightly so it worked like so:

```
.won, .keep, .discard {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Still, KingKing's answer helped me figure this out so thank you :)

Comment: I guess u need to read @kingking's comment "set explicit vertical-align:middle (or top, bottom, ...) for all the inline-block elements",
he said it for all inline-block elements, although he doesn't include that in fiddle.

Comment: looks like your actual code is different, in your demo code, all the `.won, .keep, .discard` are ***direct*** children of the `.wkd`, but in your actual code, they may not. So it won't work.

Comment: @KingKing they were direct children in my proper code too but for some reason it just didn't take effect